# How to download and read htm. file in R

Tags: r

I want to download in R information from the Commodity Futures Trading Commission website. I am specifically interested in the Commitments of Traders [report](https://www.cftc.gov/dea/options/ag_sof.htm). The file itself has the extension .htm. The required information is in the body of the page is wrapped with the

```
 <pre>
```

tag. The information itself resembles the text of dos files. Here is an example:

[image]

With the help of the following code, I was able to download this information in R:

```
 library('XML')
 
 url <- 'https://www.cftc.gov/dea/options/ag_sof.htm'
 webpage <- readLines(url, warn=FALSE)
 html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
 tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//pre")
```

the tableNodes element has the following structure:

```
 str(tableNodes)
 List of 1
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
  - attr(*, "class")= chr "XMLNodeSet"
```

Now I am stumped and do not know how to bring this object even to the form of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the fact that what you're trying to read as a table is just plain text, one way would be to transform it to a format that could be parsed with `read.` functions by using regular expressions (I used the `{stringr}` library in order to minimize calls to `gsub`).

#### remarks:

- the table always begins at the `10th` line.
- lines containing `Positions, ....` contain no other data.
- same number of columns for all rows that contain data.

#### Regexps used

- `"(?<=\n:) |:|Total Traders: +\\d+|(?<= ) +(?=[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d+)" => ""` :

  1. `(?<=\n:)`  trims whitespace.
  2. `:` removes it.
  3. `Total Traders: +\\d+` remove the total traders ...
  4. `(?<= ) +(?=[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d+)` glues the date in `: Changes from:     October 6, 2020` with the first part.
- `"  +\\n" => " "` For example glues `Positions` with the next line.
- `"  +" => "@"` converts 2 spaces or more to at symbol, as it will be used later as a seperator for values.

Testing the results:

```r
library(stringr)
txt <- ": Positions                                                                                                    :
:   16,643    17,427         0         0         0         0         0         0     1,820     1,036    11,401 :
:                                                                                                              :
: Changes from:     October 6, 2020                                                                            :
:     -264     1,739         0         0         0         0         0         0     1,122      -881       335 :
:                                                                                                              :
: Percent of Open Interest Represented by Each Category of Trader                                              :
:     55.7      58.4       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       6.1       3.5      38.2 :
:                                                                                                              :
: Number of Traders in Each Category                                  Total Traders:    22                     :
:       10        10         0         0         0         0         0         0         4         5         7 :"

cat(str_replace_all( gsub("(?<=\n:) |:|Total Traders: +\\d+| +(?=[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d+)", "", txt, perl=T), c( "  +\\n"=" ", "  +"="@")))

#> Positions@16,643@17,427@0@0@0@0@0@0@1,820@1,036@11,401 
#> Changes from October 6, 2020@-264@1,739@0@0@0@0@0@0@1,122@-881@335 
#> Percent of Open Interest Represented by Each Category of Trader@55.7@58.4@0.0@0.0@0.0@0.0@0.0@0.0@6.1@3.5@38.2 
#> Number of Traders in Each Category@10@10@0@0@0@0@0@0@4@5@7 

read.table(text=str_replace_all( gsub("(?<=\n:) |:|Total Traders: +\\d+|(?<= ) +(?=[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d+)", "", txt, perl=T), c( "  +\\n"=" ", "  +"="@")), sep="@")

#>                                                                 V1     V2     V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9   V10   V11    V12
#> 1                                                        Positions 16,643 17,427  0  0  0  0  0  0 1,820 1,036 11,401
#> 2                                     Changes from October 6, 2020   -264  1,739  0  0  0  0  0  0 1,122  -881    335
#> 3  Percent of Open Interest Represented by Each Category of Trader   55.7   58.4  0  0  0  0  0  0   6.1   3.5   38.2
#> 4                               Number of Traders in Each Category     10     10  0  0  0  0  0  0     4     5      7
```

#### `Rcode`

First we create the function that takes a full segment from the title and on and converts it to a `data.frame`. I added some code to keep some informations about each table.
[image]

```r
read.commodities <- function(x){
  txt <- paste0(x[10:length(x)], collapse="\n")
  df <- read.table(text=str_replace_all( gsub("(?<=\n:) |:|Total Traders: +\\d+| +(?=[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d+)", "", txt, perl=T), c( "  +\\n"=" ", "  +|(?<=\\d) (?=\\d)"="@")), sep="@", header=F)
  attr(df, "CFTC Code") <- str_extract(x[9],"#\\d+")
  attr(df, "Open Interest") <- trimws(str_extract(pattern="(?<=Open Interest is) +[\\d,.]+",x[9]))
  attr(df, "Commodity") <- trimws(sub(":", "", x[8]))
  attr(df, "Caption") <- trimws(x[1])
  attr(df, "Date") <- str_extract(x[1], "[A-Z][a-z]+ \\d+, \\d+")
  colnames(df) <- c("Type", "PMLong", "PMShort", "SwapDLong", "SwapDShort", "SwapDSpreading", 
  "ManagedMoneyLong", "ManagedMoneyShort", "ManagedMoneySpreading", 
  "OtherLong", "OtherShort", "OtherSpreading")
  class(df) <- c("commodities", class(df))
  df
}
```

Let commodities be the character vector containing the `pre` contents:

```
commodities %>%
  strsplit("\n-+\n(?=[^\n:]+\n)", perl=T) %>%
  lapply(strsplit, "\n") %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  lapply(read.commodities)
```

#### result for the table in the image

```
                                                              Type PMLong PMShort SwapDLong SwapDShort SwapDSpreading ManagedMoneyLong ManagedMoneyShort ManagedMoneySpreading OtherLong OtherShort OtherSpreading
1                                                        Positions  6,604  18,806         0        325             25           13,099                 0                   195         5        310           496 
2                                     Changes from October 6, 2020    811    -130         0          0              0           -1,136                 0                     0         5        119            41 
3  Percent of Open Interest Represented by Each Category of Trader   31.5    89.8         0        1.6            0.1             62.6                 0                   0.9       0.0        1.5           2.4 
4                               Number of Traders in Each Category      8      20         0          .              .                6                 0                     .         .          .             .
```

#### data

```
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html(url)
commodities <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("pre") %>%
  html_text() %>% str_replace_all(c("\\r\\n"="\n", "-+\n\n+|\n \n"=""))
```

Comment: Unconditionally correct answer. Is it possible to catch data on open interest (9th row)?

Comment: use `attr(df, "Open Interest")` and you'll the open interest for that df. If you'd want to bind all the dfs into one df I can help.

Comment: After updating the last COT report I got the following ERROR Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [12] must be the same length as the vector [11]  Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Please, need your help

Comment: the problem is  here: colnames(df) <- c("Type", "PMLong", "PMShort", "SwapDLong", "SwapDShort", "SwapDSpreading", "ManagedMoneyLong", "ManagedMoneyShort", "ManagedMoneySpreading", "OtherLong", "OtherShort", "OtherSpreading")

Comment: @JackPo can u post the link

Comment: @ Abdessabour Mtk Of the latest COT report? It's the same: https://www.cftc.gov/dea/options/ag_sof.htm

Comment: @JackPo Now it works. the error was comming from Positions line in the 5th table.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, now it works. Can you write the line you changed?

Comment: I changed `"  +"="@"` to this `"  +|(?<=\\d) (?=\\d)"="@"` in the `str_replace_all` call

Comment: Please help again with this code. After updating the last COT report I got the following ERROR: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 12 elements

Comment: I just realized that the error is in the function read.commodities

Comment: the link for the last report https://www.cftc.gov/dea/options/ag_sof.htm

Comment: @JackPo I'm thinking about wrapping this in an R package do you have any idea as to if they keep the old ones in some other url, or they just replace each one?

Comment: the link for the latest report is the same. there is an archive with past data - https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/HistoricalViewable/index.htm. Reports By Year - https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/HistoricalCompressed/index.htm

Comment: would you help with the current problem?

Comment: change this `"  +|(?<=\\d) (?=\\d)"="@"` to `"  +|(?<=\\d) (?=-?\\d)"="@"` @JackPo

Comment: @JackPo why aren't you downloading the excel formats?

Comment: I automatically update the data and if another such error go to excel. Also, I'm not sure yet if both tables are updating at the same time

Comment: @JackPo this is my email `a.moutik@insea.ma`, can u send me an email I want to iquire more about the data, cuz it appears they keep logs of data in the same format posted in your question and I want to know the difference between the excel and the text formats

Comment: @JackPo `a.moutik@insea.ac.ma` sorry my bad